# Read values from multiple YAML files in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

`spring.config.location` can accept a list of directories which host the yaml files for a spring boot application.

But the listed directories must have file named as `applicaion.yml`, else they are not picked up.

if my application allows users to place yaml files with any names then I can't use this option.

I have then manually add the file names to the property like below

`spring.config.location=/location1/file1.yml,/location2/file2.yml`

Every time a new file is added, I have to modify this property.

I was able to use `YamlPropertySourceLoader` to read all the files and put all properties into a `Map`, but is there another, more elegant, way of doing this which allows me to bind these values directly into the `@Value` annotation.

updating with the code snippet that I am currently using, but looking for any other better alternatives.

```
Resource[] resources = applicationContext.getResources("classpath*:*.properties");

        Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        Arrays.stream(resources).forEach(res -> {
            try {
                propertiesPropertySourceLoader.load("resources", res)
                        .forEach(prop -> map.putAll((Map<?, ?>) prop.getSource()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: if possible provide your approach

Comment: I use a regex to read all files on my classpath that match *yaml pattern, I feed those resources to YamlPropertySourceLoader which can be used to load all properties as a Map.

Comment: code snippet will be helpful

Comment: Updated, please have a look Abhinav.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have multiple yml/properties file in you application then you can use `@PropertySource("classpath:file.properties")` on you configuration class and accordingly you will be able to read the values from that config file.

[For more info view](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring)

Comment: This would require me to hardcode the name of the file, my case is such that the name can be anything and I dont want to change the code every time a new prop/yml file is added.

Comment: you can use placeholder to allow you to dynamically select the right file at runtime...check the link which i have shared

Comment: @PropertySource({"classpath:*.yml"}) application fails to start because of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure multiple configuration files using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for example:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="locations">
  <list>
    <value>${YOUR_HOME}/global.properties</value>
    <value>${YOUR_HOME}/second-level.properties</value>
  </list>
</property>
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
<property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF8"/>
```

Or you can use `@PropertySource` annotation for example:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:global.properties", "file://${YOUR_HOME}/second-level.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but I am trying not to hardcode the name of the file. But a regex that matches all yaml or properties files should be fine.

Comment: You can extend `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and override some methods like `setLocation` for your specific need of reading multiple with a regex pattern of file names. Also, you can use environment variables as the name of properties files.